# Big array not causing stack overflow

Tags: c, clang, stack-overflow

I can find plenty of examples of developers complaining that a big array initialized on the stack create a `stack overflow` error

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int v[100000000];
    memset(&v, 0, sizeof(v));
}
```

When compiling on Apple LLVM 7.0, this does not cause a `stack overflow`, this puzzles me as the array has a size of ~400Mb, significantly more than what is usually the size of the stack.

Why does the above code not cause `stack overflow`?

Comment: and how did you check your stack size on your environment?

Comment: Dunno anything about LVVM but if I were a compiler, I would ignore that no-op

Comment: Just because declaring a large array on the stack *risks* causing a stack overflow does not mean that you can *rely* on it to do so.

Comment: Why would that array even exist?

Comment: @AlexK. I would suspect that LLVM would ignore it actually.

Comment: Driving a car is dangerous because it can cause an accident. But I drive safe since 20 years now. Why did I not have an accident?

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh I didn't, but 100Mb is well above the standard stack size of 8Mb.

Comment: @Alex K. I have tried similar programs where I write to the first and the last index of the array, it does not cause a stack overflow.

Comment: @harold This is just for learning purposes. I agree that such an array should never exist.

Comment: @sigvardsen yes, but I don't even mean in your code, though that is also true. I see no reason for the compiler to actually allocate it here.

Comment: `as the array has a size of 100Mb`. it is sizeof(int)*100M actually

Comment: @sigvardsen On my MAC LLVM 7, setting v[0]=0 is sufficient to receive a segmentation fault

Comment: even without assignment, it crashes on mine too.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not using `v` then probably the compiler is not allocating it, try something like

```
int v[100000000];
for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(v) / sizeof(*v) ; ++i)
    v[i] = 0;
```

Comment: Perhaps `v[rand()%100000000] = 0;`  and then read the array somehow.

Comment: or you can use memset

Comment: @terencehill I know, it would requiere including *string.h* and I think the loop is more **verbose**.

Comment: @terencehill even memset may be ignored. Under Windows for example, you should use `SecureZeroMemory` if you want your zero-isation be not optimized, typically used to clear a password: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa366877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @mikedu95 But I guess it will not be ignored without optimisation. I added a comment above,  on my MAC even setting only the first element results in a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is more than 100 Mb (*) but assuming it is 100 Mb, that means that either your stack size is larger than 100 Mb, or either your compiler ignored it because you do not use it. That's a compiler optimization.

(*) Indeed 1M = 1024 * 1024, not 1000 * 1000. And one int is more than 1 bit, more than 1 Byte too. And finally, Mb means Megabit and MB means Megabyte.